# Specifying connection parameter values as registry entries in DB report mediator in WSO2 EI

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am trying to insert data into a database using the DB report mediator in WSO2 EI. Using Integration Studio 8.0.0 for developing the API. Everything works fine on hardcoding the connection parameters inline as shown below.
[image]

Now, I want to specify the connection parameters as registry entries. So, created local entries under registry config. But not sure how to set them as parameters in DB report configuration. When I tried as below, it reads the entire content of the registry local entry instead of just the value and fails. Need suggestions on how we can set the connection parameters as registry entries?
[image]
[image]
[image]